# RecordRTC in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, recordrtc

I'm trying to use an example  PHP-and-FFmpeg from the technology  RecordRTC (https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC) in Laravel project.

There is an js function:

```
function xhr(url, data, callback) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            callback(request.responseText);
        }
    };
    request.open('POST', url);
    request.send(data);
}
```

Calls for the following function:

```
function PostBlob(audioBlob, videoBlob, fileName) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('filename', fileName);
    formData.append('audio-blob', audioBlob);
    formData.append('video-blob', videoBlob);
    xhr('/upload/store', formData, function(ffmpeg_output) {
        document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = ffmpeg_output.replace(/\\n/g, '<br />');
        preview.src = 'uploads/' + fileName + '-merged.webm';
        preview.play();
        preview.muted = false;
    });
}
```

where data sends to save.php for downloading video to server.

Instead of the file i used the 'store' way, added to web.php:

```
Route::post('/upload/store', 'UploadController@store')->name('store');
```

in a controller i tenprorary made the following:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      dd($request);
}
```

but in console firefox writes:

> Invalid URI. Load of media resource  failed

Please tell me where did i make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `PostBlob` function in this line, which uses a wrong URI:

```
xhr('save.php', formData, function(ffmpeg_output) {
```

Change the `save.php` to `/upload/store`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I already changed this value, but it gives the same error

Comment: If you manually upload the file to the uploads folder, will the error go away? Could be the preview that throws the error